# How to customize elements in angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to change style of tabs in Angular Dart using SCSS but it's not working. I don't see anything wrong.

Dart code contains

```
@Component(
    selector: 'x-product-params-screen',
    styleUrls: const ['element/tabs.css', 'element/buttons.css'],
    templateUrl: 'scr_product_config.html',
...
```

element/tabs.scss contains

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';
@import 'package:angular_components/material_tab/mixins';

@include tab-panel-accent-color('.tab-panel', $mat-red);
@include tab-panel-tab-strip-width('material-tab-panel', 300px);
@include tab-strip-color('material-tab-panel', '#ff0000', '#ff00ff');
```

and template scr_product_config.html contains

```
<material-tab-panel *ngIf="product.parts.length > 1">
    <material-tab *ngFor="let part of product.parts" 
                  [label]="part.name"
                  [part]="part">
        <x-part-config
                [part]="part"
                (onConfigure)="onConfigure($event)">
        </x-part-config>
    </material-tab>
</material-tab-panel>
```

But neighter strip width nor tab color change.

Comment: could you post content of element/tabs.css?

Comment: Do you have `sass_builder: ^1.1.2` in `dev_dependencies:` in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: I had `sass_builder: ^1.0.0` in dependencies, when I put it to dev_dependencies, pub complained that it cannot be in both sections. I believe that main dependencies are used in development too.
I updated it to `^1.1.2`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at when debugging such issue is what HTML you have and what CSS was generated. I do not see class `tab-panel` in your HTML, but other than that it looks good and very similar to the [example](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/master/lib/src/material_tab_demo/material_tab_demo.scss#L9), and it seems to run fine [there](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#Tabs).
So maybe there is something else in your app that is overriding some styles?

Comment: Oh my stupid fault ... instead of quoted color codes
`@include tab-strip-color('material-tab-panel', '#ff0000', '#ff00ff');`
there should be unquoted ones :/
`@include tab-strip-color('material-tab-panel', #ff0000, #ff00ff);`